# ObjectInputStream with ID auto increment generator

Tags: java

My **videos.dat** contains some objects were stored by: V - 1000 * disks  + AI

```
Video<ID; Name; Disk; $Fee>
Video<V1001; Avenger; 1; $12.0>
Video<V1002; 50 First Dates; 1; $13.0>
Video<V2001; Furious 7; 2; $18.0>
```

And my StartUp() load to my GUI. At the startup how can I count and continue to add video Objects following auto incremental rule.

```
public void startUp() {
    int count = 0;
    try {
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("videos.dat"))) {
            objects = (Vector) ois.readObject();
            for (Object v : objects) {
                System.out.println(v.toString());
                count++;
                fireObjectCreated(v);
            }
            ois.close();
        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VideoManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VideoManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        System.out.println("Got " + count + " video objects");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("FileNotFoundException");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("IOException");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("ClassNotFoundException");
    }
}
```

I'm using HashMap to store and auto increment but after startup() my program go back to start means it started from Video **V1001**

```
public static int currentNumberOfStaticVideoID(int value) {
        if (listCountVideoID.containsKey(value)){
            System.out.println("Contain disk type " +value + " : " + listCountVideoID.containsKey(value));
            int id = listCountVideoID.get(value);
            System.out.println("Get current id: " + id);
            int newid = id + 1;
            listCountVideoID.put(value, newid);
            System.out.println("New id: " + newid);
            return newid;
        }
        int newKey = value*1000;
        listCountVideoID.put(value, newKey);
        return newKey;
    }
    public static Map<Integer, Integer> listCountVideoID = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
```

So, anyone can help to figure out some goals:

```
 + load the data file >> load objects
 + continue store video with ID = "V" + 1000*disk + AutoIncre
 + if disk = 1 > continue from V1003
 + if disk = 2 > continue from V2002
```